# How to optimize a function involving max

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am having problems minimizing a simple if slightly idiosyncratic function.  I have scipy.optimize.minimize but I can't get consistent results. Here is the full code:

```
from math import log, exp, sqrt
from bisect import bisect_left
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import Bounds
import numpy as np


def new_inflection(x0, x1):
    return log((exp(x0)+exp(x1) + sqrt(exp(2*x0)+6*exp(x0+x1)+exp(2*x1)))/2)


def make_pairs(points):
    new_points = []
    for i in range(len(points)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(points)):
            new_point = new_inflection(points[i], points[j])
            new_points.append(new_point)
    return new_points


def find_closest_number(numbers, query):
    index = bisect_left(numbers, query)
    if index == 0:
        return numbers[0]
    if index == len(numbers):
        return numbers[-1]
    before = numbers[index - 1]
    after = numbers[index]
    if after - query < query - before:
        return after
    else:
        return before

    
def max_distance(target_points):
    pair_points = make_pairs(target_points)
    target_points = sorted(target_points)
    dists = []
    return max(abs(point - find_closest_number(target_points, point)) for point in pair_points)



num_points = 20
points = np.random.rand(num_points)*10
print("Starting score:", max_distance(points))
bounds = Bounds([0]*num_points, [num_points] * num_points)
res = minimize(max_distance, points, bounds = bounds, options={'maxiter': 100}, method="SLSQP")
print([round(x,2) for x in res.x])
print(res)
```

Every time I run it I get quite different results. This is despite the output saying `Optimization terminated successfully`.  An example output:

```
 message: Optimization terminated successfully
 success: True
  status: 0
     fun: 0.4277378933292031
       x: [ 5.710e+00  1.963e+00 ...  1.479e+00  6.775e+00]
     nit: 15
     jac: [ 0.000e+00  0.000e+00 ...  0.000e+00  0.000e+00]
    nfev: 364
    njev: 15
```

Sometimes I get a result as low as 0.40 and other times as high as 0.51.

Is there any way to optimize this function properly in Python?

Comment: Obviously, `points = np.random.rand(num_points)*10` introduces a random starting point. Given the slight (or a lot?) awkwardness of your function, I'm not surprised you get roughly different answers each time. You should find and define an error on your result.

Comment: @9769953 What do you mean by an error on my result?

Comment: The minimization is an approximation, using the given algorithm. Usually, there'll be a way to find out what the uncertainty is (given by the algorithm indirectly). I can't immediately see that for `scipy.optimize.minimize` though. (This issue seems to be related: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/11233 .)

Comment: Note that you're bound to loose floating point precision, adding several exponentiations (with random values between 0 and 10), then taking a log. That's why you'll see different results each time: you loose precision in the calculations. Your function will then always be a (varying) approximation of the actual (mathematical) formula.

Comment: @9769953 I don't think that's the problem. I think it  needs a different optimizer.

Comment: If the problem is non-convex, then different results for different starting points are to be expected.  (I don't understand the problem from reading the code, so I am not sure what the mathematical model looks like). For non-nonconvex problems, we can use a global solver or do use a multi-start approach (multiple different starting points).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Which global optimiser would you recommend?

Comment: I don't want to make recommendations for a model I don't really know and a user I don't know. Depends on lots of things, both technical and otherwise (like available budget etc).

Comment: Is it possible, that since its an optimization problem; to just throw a deep neural network at it and see what happens ?

Comment: @JasonChia I would love it if you could try that and tell us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that you are exploring immense non convex search space by trying to optimize 20 variables at the same time, so usual optimization methods such as gradient descent related etc. will potentially be trapped in a local minima. In your case, as you are starting from a random coordinates each time, you end in a different local minima each time.

If the problem has no analytical solution, there is no optimizer (at least that I know) that can solve this kind of problem and guarantee you that you are in the global minimum, but that doesn't mean that we can get a very good approximations.

### Approach One

Try different types of algorithms more suited for non convex high dimension space optimization, [within scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/optimize.html#global-optimization) you have a global optimizer function:

```
from scipy import optimize
optimize.shgo(eggholder, bounds)
```

In my case that was very slow, but maybe it can help you.

**Update**:
The global optimizer basinhopping seems to give good results faster:

```
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping
res = basinhopping(max_distance, points, minimizer_kwargs={"method": "SLSQP", "bounds": bounds}, niter=100)
print([round(x,2) for x in res.x])
print(res)
```

With this optimizer you can also reach a fitness of 3.9 consistently.

### Approach Two

I would give a try to genetic algorithms using [pygad](https://pygad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), here is my trial and it reaches 3.9 fitness and consistently bellow 4.1 (though I change the sign for the optimizer).

```
import pygad

def fitness_func(solution, solution_idx):
    return -max_distance(solution)

fitness_function = fitness_func

num_generations = 500
num_parents_mating = 5

sol_per_pop = 100
num_genes = len(points)

init_range_low = 0
init_range_high = 20

parent_selection_type = "sss"
keep_parents = 5

crossover_type = "single_point"

mutation_type = "random"
mutation_percent_genes = 10

ga_instance = pygad.GA(num_generations=num_generations,
                       num_parents_mating=num_parents_mating,
                       fitness_func=fitness_function,
                       sol_per_pop=sol_per_pop,
                       num_genes=num_genes,
                       gene_space = {'low': 0, 'high': 20},
                       init_range_low=init_range_low,
                       init_range_high=init_range_high,
                       parent_selection_type=parent_selection_type,
                       keep_parents=keep_parents,
                       crossover_type=crossover_type,
                       mutation_type=mutation_type,
                       mutation_percent_genes=mutation_percent_genes)

ga_instance.run()
```

To show the solution:

```
solution, solution_fitness, solution_idx = ga_instance.best_solution()
print("Parameters of the best solution : {solution}".format(solution=solution))
print("Fitness value of the best solution = {solution_fitness}".format(solution_fitness=solution_fitness))
# plots the optimization process
ga_instance.plot_fitness(title="PyGAD with Adaptive Mutation")
```

### Approach Three

Probably the worst idea but also maybe is everything you need, Just iterate many times the algorithm you already have, with different initial conditions saving the best solution.

**Update** As the OP commented, somewhat similar to this is what the algorithm basinhopping is doing (with a bit more complexity) but it archives very good results, see approach one.

### Conclusion

There is very little you can do for having consistent results in the optimization algorithm in a problem like this one (if not fixing the seed, which I strongly discourage), but at least you can choose an algorithm that is more suited for the task maximizing the search space, so you get closer and closer to the global minimum.

On the other hand you should notice that there may be multiple/infinite solutions with the same fitness, but that can look very different, specially if there are hidden symmetries in the problem, this problem for instance seems invariant under permutations, so it would make sense to sort the solution list. Also in this case little changes in one element of the 20 numbers doesn't necessarily change the fitness.

Comment: shgo was way too slow for me too. pygad looks very useful though, thank you

Comment: nice it helps, I update to show how to show the solution in pygad

Comment: Shouldn't basinhopping using method='SLSQP' be doing approach three but better?

Comment: Yes it seems so, for what I see is a gradient + metropolis-like algorithm, where each iteration is perturbed so is less likely to fall in a local minima and also runs several times so it takes the best from all, I didn't gave it a try, but if you do and is better than the genetic, pls mention your results, will be very interesting to know.

Comment: I can't try that before the bounty deadline sadly as I am travelling

Comment: @Simd I tested it and updated my answer, it gives very good results, around 3.9 consistently, which is somewhat similar to the genetic one.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line right after your function definitions:

```
np.random.seed(0)
```

The code sets numpy's pseudorandom generator such that calls to np.random.rand() are consistent across runs. This functionality can be used for debugging probabilistic programs, or in your case, when dealing with inputs with inherent uncertainty.

Keep in mind that using np.random.seed sets the randomness of events in a sequence. I.e. if you get a random number r1=np.random.rand(), and another number r2=np.random.rand(), then you still have that r1 != r2. But if you want to really have this r1==r2 behaviour in the same script, you can simply reset the seed before the second rand call.

Do note that after debugging, that line should probably be removed.

Comment: This solution will indeed provide consistent results, but at the possible cost of always falling in the same local minima.

Comment: That is a merit of the solution, that when you are debugging you always have the same environment. That is also why I ask you to note that the line should be removed after debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a global optimization function like basin-hopping algorithm.
Your function, as it currently is, contains a non-convex objective function. So you can have multiple local maxima and minima and so will converge to a variable minima based on the initial guess.

Replace your minimization function with the basin-hopping from `scipy.optimize`.

```
from math import log, exp, sqrt
from bisect import bisect_left
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping
import numpy as np


def new_inflection(x0, x1):
    return log((exp(x0)+exp(x1) + sqrt(exp(2*x0)+6*exp(x0+x1)+exp(2*x1)))/2)


def make_pairs(points):
    new_points = []
    for i in range(len(points)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(points)):
            new_point = new_inflection(points[i], points[j])
            new_points.append(new_point)
    return new_points


def find_closest_number(numbers, query):
    index = bisect_left(numbers, query)
    if index == 0:
        return numbers[0]
    if index == len(numbers):
        return numbers[-1]
    before = numbers[index - 1]
    after = numbers[index]
    if after - query < query - before:
        return after
    else:
        return before

    
def max_distance(target_points):
    pair_points = make_pairs(target_points)
    target_points = sorted(target_points)
    dists = []
    return max(abs(point - find_closest_number(target_points, point)) for point in pair_points)


num_points = 20
points = np.random.rand(num_points)*10
print("Starting score:", max_distance(points))

res = basinhopping(max_distance, points, niter=100, stepsize=0.5, T=1.0, disp=True)

print("Optimized score:", res.fun)
print("Optimized points:", [round(x,2) for x in res.x])
print(res)
```

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: @Simd you should try it and compare to your initial results and see if it solves your dilemma

Comment: I can't try that before the bounty deadline sadly as I am travelling.